# Guard a Vue.js application with a cookie instead of localStorage

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

Thanks for stepping in.

I've watched and read thousand of articles how to guard my Vue.js application with a token stored in the localStorage.

In my application, the JWT is stored in an HttpOnly cookie, which means only the server can read its value.

In the "traditional" way I would implement login and logout methods where I set and unset a value in the localStorage, and in my router I would add:

```
router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
    const loggedIn = localStorage.getItem('token');

    if (to.matched.some(record => record.meta.requiresAuth && !loggedIn)) {
        // Some failure logic.
    }
    next()
});
```

But in my case I can't do that, and I wonder what would be the best way to set a guard to my frontend application?

I've tried a bit different way for my use:

```
router.beforeEach(async (to, from, next) => {
    if (to.matched.some((record) => record.meta.requiresAuth)) {
        try {
            await store.dispatch(`authModule/fetchUserData`);
        } catch (e) {
        // Some failure logic.
        }
    }

    next();
});
```

But basically this action occurs every tab and of course other actions are being dispatched before I get an answer for that request.

I wonder, is that best way just to return 403 response for each request and set an interceptor in the axios so once I get the 403 I would logout the user?

Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: Is a cookie used for a reason? localStorage is conventionally used because it fits the case, while httpOnly cookie doesn't.

Comment: @EstusFlask Yes, it is shared by all of the sub-domains, also, cookies with HttpOnly considered more secured than localStoage (if you use with extra caution)

Comment: It isn't more secure, both cookies and LS can be modified or stolen from user's side. Unless you mean XSS which LS is sensitive to, but then LS is a lesser problem because anything that happens on client side is compromised, a culprit can tamper any of your HTTP requests, including the ones that contain httpOnly cookie. httpOnly cookie defies the purpose of JWT as a self-sufficient auth mechanism. You can do this with httpOnly cookie, but you need to do extra request to extra API endpoint just to get the contents of JWT.

Comment: This seems to be very impractical and likely is the reason why you found a ton of LS but no httpOnly cookie examples. If a security is a real issue for you, don't persist JWT on client side and reissue them for every session, it can be stored in a variable. As for subdomains, it's a known issue for LS and there are workarounds that are less cumbersome than httpOnly workflow.

Comment: So, do you suggest just use localStorage?

Comment: Yes, I'd look no further than LS for regular JWT, no storage or sessionStorage for more secure JWT unless there are real reasons to reconsider this. Hope this helps, despite this doesn't answer your question that deserves an answer at least for educational purposes.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help, hopefully will answer as you said for educational purposes.